How to update a state that will affect another state in the process React
I was trying to update inferredFacts state, but in the process it has to update facts state first, then get the updated value of facts state then process the inferredFacts, the problem is the inferredFacts won't get the updated value of the facts
i've tried using useEffect and useMemo but it's just give me infinite loop, though i'm not sure if i'm implementing it right.
BTW I'm working on forward chaining
export default function useFacts(answers: boolean[]) {
  const [facts, setFacts] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set([]));
  const [inferredFacts, setInferredFacts] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set([]));

  const addFact = useCallback((newFact: string) => {
    setFacts((prevFacts) => new Set([...prevFacts, newFact]));
  }, []);

  function populateFacts() {
    const tmpFacts = new Set<string>([]);
    if (answers[0]) {
      tmpFacts.add("a");
    }
    if (answers[1]) {
      tmpFacts.add("b");
    }
    if (answers[2]) {
      tmpFacts.add("c");
    }
    if (answers[3]) {
      tmpFacts.add("f");
    }

    setFacts(tmpFacts);
  }

  const factsHasAll = useCallback(
    // list = antecedent
    (list: string[]) => {
      const filteredFacts = list.filter((item) => facts.has(item));

      if (filteredFacts.length === list.length) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    },
    [facts]
  );

  const doForwardChaining = useCallback(
    (rules: Rule[]) => {
      const inferredFacts = new Set<string>([]);

      while (true) {
        let inferred = false;
        for (const rule of rules) {
          if (
            factsHasAll(rule.antecedent) &&
            !inferredFacts.has(rule.consequent)
          ) {
            addFact(rule.consequent);
            inferredFacts.add(rule.consequent);
            inferred = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!inferred) break;
      }

      setInferredFacts((prev) => new Set([...prev, ...inferredFacts]));
    },
    [addFact, factsHasAll]
  );

  return {
    facts,
    populateFacts,
    doForwardChaining,
    inferredFacts,
  };
}



You are updating the state, which is an async operation, and then synchronously checking if the state changes.
Instead, you'll have to take the current state, create tempFacts Set, update and check it synchronously, and when done update the state.
const answersToFact = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f'] as const;

// this functions accept both list and facts, so we can extract it out of the component
const factsHasAll = (list: string[], facts: Set<string>) => list.every(item => facts.has(item));

export default function useFacts(answers: boolean[]) {
  const [facts, setFacts] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set([]));
  const [inferredFacts, setInferredFacts] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set([]));

  function populateFacts() {
    setFacts(answersToFacts.reduce((set, fact, idx) => {
      if(answer[idx]).add(fact);
      
      return set;
    }, new Set<string>()));
  }

  const doForwardChaining = useCallback(
    (rules: Rule[]) => {
      const inferredFacts = new Set<string>([]);
      const tempFacts = new Set(facts); // create a temp facts state

      while (true) {
        let inferred = false;
        for (const rule of rules) {
          if (
            // check if all facts exists in the tempFacts
            factsHasAll(rule.antecedent, tempFacts) &&
            !inferredFacts.has(rule.consequent)
          ) {
            tempFacts.add(rule.consequent); // update tempFacts
            inferredFacts.add(rule.consequent);
            inferred = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!inferred) break;
      }

      setFacts(facts);
      setInferredFacts((prev) => new Set([...prev, ...inferredFacts]));
    },
    [facts]
  );

  return {
    facts,
    populateFacts,
    doForwardChaining,
    inferredFacts,
  };
}


Thanks for the answer
